# How to display NSMutableArray results on a mapview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, mkmapview

I'm trying to get the locations using the `Google Places API` and display them on a `mapView` I have a `NSMutableArray` called myList. The `NSLog` output from myList is

```
Project[3151:15803] mylist array (
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa040>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa140>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa170>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa1a0>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa1d0>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81a9f20>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81a9f50>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81a9f80>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81a9fb0>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa260>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa290>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa2c0>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa2f0>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa320>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa350>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa380>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa3b0>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa450>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa480>",
    "<ObjectInfo: 0x81aa4b0>"
```

and I am trying to place it on the map using   `[self.mapView addAnnotations:myList];`

It seems like I need to access the coordinates somehow and display the locations that way. I'm not sure. thanks for any help.

here's my code:

```
- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager 
{
    if (locationManager != nil) 
    {
        return locationManager;
    }

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    return locationManager;

}

- (void)showAnnotation
{

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = theCoordinate;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;
    region.span=span;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];

    DDAnnotation *annotation = [[[DDAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:theCoordinate addressDictionary:nil] autorelease];

    NSLog(@"mylist array %@", myList);

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:myList];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f)];
    [activityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(160.0f, 208.0f)];
    [activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicator.tag = INDICATOR_VIEW;
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator release];


    self.myTable = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400) style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
    [self.myTable setDelegate:self];
    [self.myTable setDataSource:self];  
    [self.myTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.myTable setRowHeight:74];
    [self.myTable setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    //[self.myTable setScrollEnabled:NO];

   // self.myTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone; // none style

    [self.view addSubview:self.myTable];


    if ([ProjUtil connectedToWeb]) {


        self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self; // send loc updates to myself
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


        //UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[self.view viewWithTag:INDICATOR_VIEW];

        [activityIndicator startAnimating];
        [backBt setEnabled:NO];
        [myTable setUserInteractionEnabled:NO ];
    }   else {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Internet connection fails" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

}

// Listen to change in the userLocation
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context 
{       
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;  

    MKCoordinateSpan span; 
    span.latitudeDelta  = 0.05; // Change these values to change the zoom
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.05; 
    region.span = span;

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 

    UILabel* nameLb;
    UILabel* detailsLb; 

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"log-cell"]; 

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:@"log-cell"] autorelease];

        UIImage* img = [ImgUtil image:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"butList3_%d.png", [[SelectCategory instance] select] + 1 ]];
        UIImageView* bgImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img ]autorelease];
        [cell addSubview:bgImage ];
        [cell sendSubviewToBack:bgImage ];

        nameLb = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 5, 250, 40)] autorelease];
        [nameLb setNumberOfLines:4];
        [nameLb setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [nameLb setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [nameLb setTag:NAME_TEXT];
        [nameLb setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15]];
        [nameLb setMinimumFontSize:10];

        [cell addSubview:nameLb];


        detailsLb = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 45, 250, 20)] autorelease];
        [detailsLb setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [detailsLb setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [detailsLb setTag:DETAILS_TEXT];
        [detailsLb setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
        [cell addSubview:detailsLb];


    }else {

        nameLb = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:NAME_TEXT];
        detailsLb = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:DETAILS_TEXT];

    }

    ObjectInfo* obj = [myList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] ;
    nameLb.text = [obj name];

    double distance = [ProjUtil getDistanceWithLat1:currentLocation.latitude long1:currentLocation.longitude lat2:obj.location.latitude long2:obj.location.longitude];
    detailsLb.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f miles", [ProjUtil kmToMi:distance]];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    ///[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    return cell;

} 

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 

    MoreInfoCtrl* _ctrl = [MoreInfoCtrl make];
    _ctrl.object = [myList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_ctrl animated:YES];

} 

-(void) findCodeWithCoord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) _coord{
    //[[SelectCategory instance] getCategoryText]

    NSString* request = [NSString stringWithFormat:LINK,_coord.latitude , _coord.longitude , [[SelectCategory instance] getCategoryText]];
    //NSLog(@"%@", request);
    request = [request stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"%@", request);
    NSObject* requestJSON = [ServerInfoResuest getServerInfoWithAddress:request];
    NSMutableDictionary* allInfo = (NSMutableDictionary* ) requestJSON;

    if ([[allInfo objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
        self.myList = [ObjectParse parserManager:[allInfo objectForKey:@"results"]]; 
//        NSLog(@"allinfo dict is %@", allInfo);

    }

    [myTable reloadData];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[self.view viewWithTag:INDICATOR_VIEW];

    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    [backBt setEnabled:YES];
    [myTable setUserInteractionEnabled:YES ];


}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{   
    //[self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation];
    currentLocation = newLocation.coordinate;
    //  errorLabel.text = [newLocation description];
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation]; 
    [self findCodeWithCoord:currentLocation];

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; 
    theCoordinate.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    theCoordinate.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    [self showAnnotation];
}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    AddressAnnotation* adr = (AddressAnnotation*) annotation;
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)
    [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:adr.placeTitle];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                               initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:adr.placeTitle] autorelease];
        //      customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wpin.png"]];

        AddressAnnotation* adr = (AddressAnnotation*) annotation;

        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clDetails) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        customPinView.draggable = YES;
        customPinView.animatesDrop = NO;
        customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;

  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        //  customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        return customPinView;
    }
    return nil; 
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[self.view viewWithTag:INDICATOR_VIEW];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [backBt setEnabled:YES];
    [myTable setUserInteractionEnabled:YES ];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];


}

@end
```

Comment: where and how `myList` is populated?

Comment: from a JSON request: NSObject* requestJSON = [ServerInfoResuest getServerInfoWithAddress:request];
 NSMutableDictionary* allInfo = (NSMutableDictionary* ) requestJSON;
 
 if ([[allInfo objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
  self.myList = [ObjectParse parserManager:[allInfo objectForKey:@"results"]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the annotation, you should be giving it a CLLocationCoordinate2D which contains the latitude and longitude.  You of course would be getting this from the JSON object which you have to parse. The below line is definitely right, that is all you have to do, this goes through your myList and adds each annotation to the map view.  Make sure your annotation contains a longitude and latitude (i.e. a coordinate)

```
[self.mapView addAnnotations:myList];
```

Check the link below, great tutorial.

http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2011/07/working-with-google-places-api.html